# How can i retrieve data from a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working in PHP. This is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        from place as s 
        where checkDistance($lati1,$longi1,s.lat,s.lon)<$dist";
```

This place table has three fields: **placeId**, **PlaceName** and **Address**. Now I want to calculate rating of **placeId** which are the result of above query. To calculate the rating I have another table **rating** in which there are two fields: **placeId** and **noOfPerson**.

Rating will be calculated by **(noOfPerson/maximum_no_of_person)** for each placeId. How can i implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could do majority of work here, this will select values from `place` table joined with number of person for each place, ordered by ranking you need, top-bottom:

```
SELECT s.placeid, s.PlaceName, s.Address, r.noOfPerson
FROM place as s JOIN rating as r ON (s.placeid = r.placeid)
WHERE checkDistance($lati1,$longi1,s.lat,s.lon)
ORDER BY r.noOfPerson / ( SELECT MAX(noOfPerson) FROM rating ) DESC
```